# SQL: Missing keyword, Foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I am trying to create a table with a foreign key, but I keep on getting a missing keyword error. Any headers on what may be causing the problem?

```
 Create table CAR
(vin varchar2(7),
SaleDate date,
SalePrice number (7,2),
Balance_due number (7, 2),
date_bought date,
miles number(6), 
CONSTRAINT pkcar PRIMARY KEY(vin),
CONSTRAINT fkcar1 FOREIGN KEY(BrName) REFRENCES BRANCH,
CONSTRAINT fkcar4 FOREIGN KEY(CarTypeCode) REFRENCES CARTYPE,
CONSTRAINT fkcar2 FOREIGN KEY(BuyerId) REFRENCES CUSTOMER,
CONSTRAINT fkcar3 FOREIGN KEY(SellerId) REFRENCES CUSTOMER);
```

The error reads:
    Error at line 9: ORA-00905:missing keyword

I have already created the other tables (BRANCH, CARTYPE, CUSTOMER) and set their primary keys as (BrName, CarTypeCode, CustId).

Comment: REFRENCES should be references i guess ..

Answer (score 4):

<strike>`REFRENCES`</strike> is spelled `REFERENCES`

Answer (score 0):

REFRENCES should be references i guess .. and you are not specifying the column of the parent table CONSTRAINT fk_column
  FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
  REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)

Comment: In Standard SQL when referencing by PRIMARY KEY (rather than by UNIQUE constraint) the columns in the referenced table do not need to specified, looks like mySQL is non-compliant. p.s. "should be references i guess" -- correct, and that is why we say, "referenced table". The term "parent table" implies a different kind of relationship.